How to get iOS to actually completely update and release the screen, the UI, between each step, when for example loading a stack?
Here's something I have never been able to figure out in UIKit.
In Xcode click a new app project, swift/sboard
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let stack = UIStackView.Typical
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _setup()
    }
    
    @objc func load() {
        stack.removeFullyAll()
        for _ in 1...50 {
            let l = UILabel.Typical
            l.backgroundColor = .randomSoft
            l.text = [String](repeating: "string", count: 20).joined(separator: " ")
            stack.addArrangedSubview(l)
        }
    }
    
    func _setup() {
        let scroll = UIScrollView.Typical
        view.addSubview(scroll)
        scroll.addSubview(stack)
        scroll.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 2
        
        let b = UIButton.Typical
        view.addSubview(b)
        b.setImage(.init(systemName: "wand.and.stars"), for: [])
        b.setTitle(" fill ", for: [])
        b.backgroundColor = .yellow
        b.setTitleColor(.label, for: [])
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(load), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scroll.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 50),
            scroll.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -50),
            scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100),
            stack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leftAnchor, constant: 2),
            stack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.rightAnchor, constant: -2),
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.topAnchor, constant: 2),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.bottomAnchor, constant: -2),
            b.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leftAnchor),
            b.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.topAnchor, constant: -4),
        ])
    }
}

extension UIView {
    static var Typical: Self {
        let v = Self()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        return v
    }
}
extension UIColor {
    static var randomSoft: UIColor {
        return UIColor(hue: CGFloat(Int.random(in: 0..<20)) / 20.0,
          saturation: 0.3, brightness: 0.8, alpha: 1)
    }
}
extension UIStackView {
    func removeFully(view: UIView) {
        removeArrangedSubview(view)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    func removeFullyAll() {
        arrangedSubviews.forEach { (view) in
            removeFully(view: view)
        }
    }
}


Run, and tap the fill button.  It will "instantly" populate.
Now try
        for _ in 1...2000 {

depending on your machine, it will now hang for a few seconds, while it figures this out.
Here's the thing. I want it to

put in one view
actually "do that", and draw it to the screen via the window engine (or whatever the hell it's doing)
start thinking about the next one,
do that one and repeat

Purely to illustrate, now swap in this function:
@objc func load() {
    stack.removeFullyAll()
    for i in 1...2000 {
        delay(Double(i) * 0.05) {
            let l = UILabel.Typical
            l.backgroundColor = .randomSoft
            l.text = [String](repeating: "string", count: 20).joined(separator: " ")
            self.stack.addArrangedSubview(l)
        }
    }
}

Run.  Notice it works, illustratively, beautifully - it brings them in one by one, and, you can continually scroll in two directions etc as it does so, the scroll bars slowly reshape etc.
(Note this does not of course "work really well", it's just a demo to explain the desired outcome. the .05 is a mess obviously and the approximate needed time goes haywire as it gets bigger; try an even larger count, 10,000 or such, and it collapses. Again this is just a demo to show you the desired outcome.)
Now, I've always thought that this sort of thing should work,
@objc func load() {
    stack.removeFullyAll()
    for _ in 1...550 {
        let l = UILabel.Typical
        l.backgroundColor = .randomSoft
        l.text = [String](repeating: "string", count: 20).joined(separator: " ")
        stack.addArrangedSubview(l)
        
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        print("wth")
    }
}

But it does not work - try it.  (It's actually much slower.)
Knock yourself out, try
        stack.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

or any combination. try throwing in
        RunLoop.main.run(mode: .common, before: Date.now)

as much as you want .. no good.
(PS, I don't care about stack views in particular, this comes up all the time when you're building "lots and lots of stuff"; I just used a stack view in this here demo since it's easy to paste. An equal demo would be, say, just stick 10,00 labels on the screen each with two constraints - whatever.)
I've explained it as clearly as can be. How the heck to get the UI thread to take over, do it's stuff, release again, and then do its stuff again - note how everything still responsive throughout the progressive build in the cheap "0.05" demo.
Why doesn't layoutIfNeeded do this, am I making some mistake, why does triggering the run loop do nothing?
How to achieve it?

You shouldn't do this in the first place. Surely you don't need 1000 labels all simultaneously on the screen? Show them lazily like a UITableView or UICollectionView. If you do need that many labels on the screen, consider using APIs like CALayer that can run off the main thread to do the drawing.

Why does layoutIfNeeded (and even tripping the run loop) seemingly not work as one would expect?  If you arrange to wait a frame (which is a mess but can be done) it STILL doesn't work as in the "crappy 0.05 example". What is it that stays locked up? Is it because the function that is happening (load in the example) is still active?  It's clearly an enormous hole in (my, anyway) understanding of the most basic elements of how UIKit does stuff, it's incredible I (and seemingly everyone) has not a clue how to do this, how layoutIfNeeded etc works!

I'm not sure why you'd think layoutIfNeeded or setNeedsLayout would change anything... Layout is not the problem at all here. The problem is you are running a very long loop synchronously.

I'm not sure why you think layoutIfNeeded and setNeedsLayout are relevant.
RunLoop.run is going in the right direction, but you are running it in the wrong mode. I don't know what modes the .common set includes, but evidently is not solely .tracking, which is the mode used to handle user interactions with the UI.
If I understand your goal correctly, RunLoop.main.run(mode: .tracking, before: .now) is what you are looking for.
However, just like your delay example, this will still become laggy after a while, because then the bottleneck is going to be redoing the layout of everything. As the number of views increases, redoing the layout is going to take longer and longer, and you have no control over that.
This is less of a problem if there is no UIStackView adjusting all the constraints every time you add an arranged subview. Here I just used a simple UIView as the parent of the labels, and added my own UIStackView-like constraints. Furthermore, I precomputed the height of the scroll view content, so the scroll view content size doesn't have to update every time a new label gets added. It runs relatively quickly for me:

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let stack = UIView.Typical
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _setup()
    }
    
    @objc func load() {
        stack.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        var prevLabel: UILabel? = nil
        for _ in 1...2000 {
            let l = UILabel.Typical
            l.backgroundColor = .randomSoft
            l.text = [String](repeating: "string", count: 20).joined(separator: " ")
            
            stack.addSubview(l)
            
            let topAnchor = prevLabel?.bottomAnchor ?? stack.topAnchor
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                l.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.leadingAnchor),
                l.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.trailingAnchor),
                l.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            ])
            
            prevLabel = l
            
            RunLoop.main.run(mode: .tracking, before: .now)
        }
    }
    
    func _setup() {
        let scroll = UIScrollView.Typical
        view.addSubview(scroll)
        scroll.addSubview(stack)
        scroll.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        
        // create a temporary label to find the height of the text
        let l = UILabel.Typical
        l.text = "string"
        l.sizeToFit()
        let height = l.bounds.height
        
        let b = UIButton.Typical
        view.addSubview(b)
        b.setImage(.init(systemName: "wand.and.stars"), for: [])
        b.setTitle(" fill ", for: [])
        b.backgroundColor = .yellow
        b.setTitleColor(.label, for: [])
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(load), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scroll.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 50),
            scroll.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -50),
            scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            stack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leftAnchor, constant: 2),
            stack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.rightAnchor, constant: -2),
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.topAnchor, constant: 2),
            stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height * 2000),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.bottomAnchor),
            b.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.leftAnchor),
            b.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scroll.topAnchor, constant: -4)
        ])
    }
}

This is all to say that you are using UIKit incorrectly. Consider not doing this in the first place. Surely you don't need 1000 labels all simultaneously on the screen? Show them lazily like a UITableView or UICollectionView. If you do need that many labels on the screen, consider using lower-level APIs like CALayer that can run off the main thread to do the drawing.

Investigating RunLoop.main.run(mode: .tracking, before: .now) !!

"you have no control over that" I really find that difficult to understand

@Fattie What I mean is that you cannot change the implementation of AutoLayout to add calls to RunLoop.main.run so that it yields during layout. Even if you could, what would a half laid-out UI look like?

@Fattie I have added a slightly edited version of the code which doesn't use UIStackView and have the scroll view content size as a constant value. This runs relatively quickly. In general though, you should use a UICollectionView instead. That's the whole point of UICollectionView.

Cheers @Sweeper, sorry, there must be something unclear with my writing (example, (PS, I don't care about stack views in particular, this comes up all the time when you're building "lots and lots of stuff"; I just used a stack view in this here demo since it's easy to paste. An equal demo would be, say, just stick 10,00 labels on the screen each with two constraints - whatever.)) I (for some years now :) ) am completely familiar with recycling views, drawing offscreden with CALayer, etc :) Hence Consider not doing this in the first place yes we're definitely having two different conversati

ons :)  I'm unclear what made you think I would "do this", the question is pretty clear "How to get iOS to actually completely update and release the screen, the UI, between each step"; I'm not trying to "do" anything, ie, I'm not, say, stuck on how to do a table view for a client app :) :)  Note that your fixed-height demo is, identically, an example showing the issue at hand, it just "does it less", that's why I made a demo with a stack view, as it makes the issue more clear, it's a good demo of the issue. Note that when you say "Even if you could, what would a half laid-out UI look like",

it looks precisely as in the "0.05" demo. It does one, stops, does the next one etc.  (Again importantly, note that the .05 demo "doesn't work" - once it gets too big it again falls over itself and hangs. That's really the nature of what I'm asking, how to get it to "finish all its doing" and/or "know its' finished what it is doing")

It's possible the answer to my question is:  you say: this will still become laggy after a while correct, that's what I'm discussing, because then the bottleneck is going to be redoing the layout of everything. quite right As the number of views increases, redoing the layout is going to take longer and longer now you've got it! how do I know when the layout is finished, and you have no control over that. !!! So the answer is "you have absolutely no control over it, and, there is absolutely no alert whatsoever from the window/whatever engine that it's done"  ..???!

If so I guess that's all there is to it, but it's kind of bizarre

@Fattie Okay, why would knowing when the layout is finished, help with anything? It is the layout itself that causes the lag. This is just how long it takes to lay out so many constraints. You are hitting the limit of AutoLayout, basically.

BTW I hesitate to mention a "use case" because, again, I'm not trying to "do" anything, I'm trying to get to the bottom of how iOS works; but an everyday common example is, regarding text, I'm sure you've had the common problem of drawing, imagine just a large grid of text (perhaps growing), unknown column widths, and you're trying to endlessly resize all the cols to the max width of the string in that column; that's a good example where the simplest moist elegant approach is you need to know when its finished doing the last measurement or re-layout (again, I'm incredibly familiar with the str

ategies for doing that, I'm simply giving it as an example of how, let's put it this way, "knowing when the layout engine has settled down" is a key and natural component of such an undertaking.

@Fattie Well, the layout finishes when there is no lag. UIKit blocks the main thread when computing the layout, by design. It cannot lay things out on another thread.

"Okay, why would knowing when the layout is finished, help with anything" for simplicity (also, I hate sort of "wasting your time" as apparently I was just not clear enough in the meta here), for simplicity "I just want to know"  :) To increase my understanding of the overall engine.  I hope that makes sense; put it this way maybe I should have spelled that out to begin with - anyway!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"the layout finishes when there is no lag" it does seem incredible there isn't a way to know that.  "blocks the main thread when computing the layout..."  are you basically saying "so just watch for each new frame (ie presumably with cadisplaylink) and when it comes back - that's it!"  If so, wild, however, I have indeed often tinkered around with that (as mentioned briefly in the Q) and it does not seem to work. (However, I may be wrong)  My guess is that it seems to give up some frames but still be doing stuff, I don't know.

lol I will after a few meetings!  :)

My God!  .tracking seems to be the secret sauce!
